# Managed patch solution not reflecting changes made in optionset

Tags: dynamics-crm, patch, managed

I have a solution in Dynamics CRM which serves as the base and I have made the corresponding changes in patch solution. 
The change was to make  tag to 0 
I see that on importing unmanaged base and patch solution, the optionsets were reflected as non-customizable but in case of importing managed base and patch solution, the same changes are not reflected

What could be the problem?

Comment: Please add more context to your question (in the form of code/data/example)

Comment: Please rephrase this sentence. "The change was to make tag to 0 I see that on importing unmanaged base and patch solution, the optionsets were reflected as non-customizable". It is wery difficult to understand what has been changed.